# How can I see what Major and Minor modes I'm currently in?

Tags: major-mode, minor-mode, help

Is there an easy way to see what modes are currently operating in a buffer? And have a list of their names?

Answer (score 4):

Almost every mode puts some kind of text in the mode line, which is the line of text at the bottom of every buffer. You can also type `C-h m` (or `M-x describe-mode`)to get long-form documentation about every mode that is currently active. This includes their names as well as all of their keybindings.

Comment: C-h m? Ctrl + h and then m?

Comment: I can do ctrl-c ctrl-h to get into a help screen. But then I'm in a help buffer. I want to see the modes enabled in the buffer I'm currently working in. (And to get a list of their names, not just see the mode line ... I'm trying to understand what the mode line is actually telling me)

Comment: Yes, Ctrl+h and then m. This calls the command `describe-mode`  for whatever buffer you are currently in. The result is a new buffer that lists all the enabled modes and describes each one.

Comment: That's not working for me. Ctrl+h just takes me to the top of the buffer :-(

Comment: @interstar C-h m opens a help buffer that lists all the modes that are active in the buffer you started in. You *should* end up in a help buffer.

Comment: OK ... I can do that (ctl-c ctl-h) But if I go on to type "m" it doesn't seem to call the describe-mode function.

Comment: Why are you doing C-c? C-h m, no C-c

Comment: Because C-h just takes me to the top of the buffer.

Comment: Start from `emacs -Q`. Something in your init file is making Emacs use different key bindings, so you and those commenting here are not communicating. Otherwise, use `M-x describe-mode` to get past the communication blockage.

Comment: OK ... I guess that's it, but M-x describe-mode was really what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you'll also want to know about `describe-key` and `describe-function`. `describe-key` lets you type in a key sequence, and it tells you what command that sequence will run. `describe-function` prompts for a function name and gives you the documentation of that function, as well as what keys it is bound to. In this case you could run `M-x describe-function describe-function` to get the help for `describe-function` as well as to find out what key or keys it is bound to, if any. Then you can use that keyboard shortcut in place of `C-h m`.

Comment: @db48x I think you should add the previous comment to your answer.

Comment: n.b. It's probably best *not* to clobber the primary "help" key binding in your Emacs config (or indeed for any application), if you're liable to forget that you've done it.  However, if you're determined to keep your custom `C-h` binding, then try using `<f1>` in its place.  Assuming you haven't also clobbered that, you can just mentally substitute that for `C-h` when you see those key sequences.